# Microsoft Message Analyzer and Windows Advanced Firewall ipsec tunnel packet sniffing

Tags: windows, ipsec, windows-firewall, packet-sniffer

I am trying to view connections or attempted connections in windows advanced firewall. I have tried using the Windows Firewall Service provider however the trace does not return anything. Any ideas?